# capture data of a slickgrid using UiPath

Tags: slickgrid, uipath

I am trying to scrap data from a slickgrid, but it isn't working out. It has problems with selector or meta data. I have tried using wildcards, and other alternatives too, but all fail to scrap the data. Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to get to know Slickgrid a bit to work out what to do. Slickgrid only displays the currently visible data, so scraping the data from the UI will only get partial results.

The best thing to do would be to find the underlying data object and print it as JSON. However this would be impossible to do in a general sense (ie. for any website).
It's relatively easy for a single target website, and may be able to be automated with a few tricks for multiple renderings of the same page of a specific website.

(edit: whoops, just noticed the UIPath bit. I had a look, but I don't know how it works. Assume it looks in the HTML. Basically, that will only work if you are able to get UiPath to scroll through the entire dataset one page at a time. You'll have to use logic to eliminate the metadata rows. But if you can drop into javascript, it will be *so* much easier)

Comment: I have to automate an application based on finch framework and there is a task to capture the data from a slickgrid and compare it with a dataset and display a pass or fail.